# DataContract For Serialization in ASP.NET Web API 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, odata, xml-serialization

I have entity model classes generated from the database. I am trying to use annotations on these classes. The moment I update my classes from the database the annotations are wiped out. Remember the annotations are related to serialization.

For example

```
[DataContract]
public partial class A
{
   [DataMember]
   [Key]
   public int id;
   [DataMember]
   public string name;
}
```

I have tried using MetaData/Buddy classes but nothing seems like working. Is their a way to preserve these annotations in the model classes?

Comment: Are you using json serialization or xml?  With json serialization, you don't need these attributes.

Comment: Well I am trying to use ODATA with web api2. I am not using JSON serialization as in future the client might be using XML format to communicate data.